# How would I translate an ease in out function from c++ to python?

Tags: c++, python

I have been attempting to translate a function from C++ to Python for a while but I cannot understand the function well enough to translate it on my own.

```
//C++
float Cubic::easeInOut(float t,float b , float c, float d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;    
}

//Python
def rotate(t, b, c, d):
    t = t/(d/2)
    if (t < 1):
        return c/2*t*t*t + b
    t = t-2
    return c/2*((t)*t*t + 2) + b
```

Edit: this is what i got so far but it doesn't return a list that rises from 0.0 to 1.0.
Has anyone ever done this in python before?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: first, simplify the C++

```
struct Cubic { 
    float easeInOut(float t,float b , float c, float d) {
        t = t / (d/2);
        if (t < 1) 
            return c/2*t*t*t + b;
        t = t - 2;
        return c/2*(t*t*t + 2) + b;   
    } 
}
```

Now if you can't figure out how to translate *that* to python, then you need to learn more python.  I was able to translate this to python and I don't even *know* python.

Actually, now that you've posted your python, and you claim it's wrong, it occurs to me that all numbers in python are (probably, I'm guessing here) doubles, which means each time you divide it will do so slightly differently than C++ would.  A quick glance at the Python docs says "`The / (division) and // (floor division) operators yield the quotient of their arguments.`", so apparently you should use `//` if you want it to act like the C++.

Comment: Thank you for the simplification.  It helps!  Perhaps I don't know c++ well enough.

Comment: Interestingly, you are right, it does change the output but the output is still a single number as opposed to a changing value.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you replace all the numeric constants (e.g. 2) with their float constant equivalents (e.g. 2.0) ?

```
def rotate(t, b, c, d):
    t = t/(d/2.0)
    if t < 1.0:
        return c/2.0*t*t*t + b
    t = t-2.0
    return c/2.0*((t)*t*t + 2.0) + b
```

Comment: I was going to say "of course not!" But the more I thought about it.... this could very well be his issue...

Comment: Ok, I tried setting all of my constants to floats including the declared variables.  still spits out the same number.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a correct translation, but it's not intended to return a list. This easing function returns a *single* eased time value for the provided time (t). It's intended to be called multiple times with a t value that varies from 0 to d and returns a result that varies from b to b+c in a smooth (non-linear) fashion.

You want the return to go from 0 to 1, so you should call this with b=0.0 and c=1.0. The d value you should set to the duration of time you want to ease over.

To get a list for eased values from 0 to 1, for t from 0 to 10 you could do something like this:

```
[rotate(t,0.0,1.0,10.0) for t in range(11)]
```

result:

```
[0.0, 0.004000000000000001, 0.03200000000000001, 0.108, 0.25600000000000006, 0.5, 0.744, 0.8919999999999999, 0.968, 0.996, 1.0]
```

Comment: Parameters for start and end, along with resolution, could be added to the function, so that the list comprehension will happen inside a single function call, instead of having `r` function calls inside the list comprehension.